# Byte string to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, byte

I receive serial data byte string `b'001  000000000000000000  000 4.98 135.1 100.8 0.00 0.00   6.6\r\n'` from machine. How to create a list like `[001, 000000000000000000, 000, 4.98, 135.1, 100.8, 0.00, 6.6]`?

Comment: Check the split() function.

Answer (score 0):

Here my ans, using strip to remove \r \n and split (default whitespace) to split in list

```
s = b'001 000000000000000000 000 4.98 135.1 100.8 0.00 0.00 6.6\r\n'
l = s.strip().split()
```

OUTPUT

```
['001', '000000000000000000', '000', '4.98', '135.1', '100.8', '0.00', '0.00', '6.6']
```

Comment: This preserves the byte class, not strings. It outputs `[b'001', b'000000000000000000', b'000', b'4.98', b'135.1', b'100.8', b'0.00', b'0.00', b'6.6']`. Also OP seems to want the output values as `floats`

Comment: @yatu Thats not true, they are string not byte on list. >>> print(l)
['001', '000000000000000000', '000', '4.98', '135.1', '100.8', '0.00', '0.00', '6.6']
>>> print(repr(l))
['001', '000000000000000000', '000', '4.98', '135.1', '100.8', '0.00', '0.00', '6.6']

Answer (score 0):

first, convert bytes into string then remove \r\n with strip()
at last split on the basis of space

```
a = b'001 000000000000000000 000 4.98 135.1 100.8 0.00 0.00 6.6\r\n' 
print(a.decode("utf-8").strip().split())
```

results

```
['001', '000000000000000000', '000', '4.98', '135.1', '100.8', '0.00', '0.00', '6.6']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

- [decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)- Return a string decoded from the given bytes.
- [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) -  Returns a list of strings after breaking the given string by the specified separator.
- float() - Return a floating-point number from a number or a string.

**Ex.**

```
str1 = b'001 000000000000000000 000 4.98 135.1 100.8 0.00 0.00 6.6\r\n'
my_list = [float(i) for i in str1.decode("utf-8").split()]
print(my_list)
```

**O/P:**

```
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.98, 135.1, 100.8, 0.0, 0.0, 6.6]
```

Comment: @yatu thanks for the info. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    str =b'001  000000000000000000  000 4.98 135.1 100.8 0.00 0.00   6.6\r\n'
    Result =[i for i in str.strip().split()]
    #Result = ['001', '000000000000000000', '000', '4.98', '135.1', '100.8', '0.00', '0.00', '6.6']
```